# Add slides HTML and CSS carousel

Tags: html, css

I found some code to create a carousel using HTML and CSS only. I managed to add an extra slide (slide 4) but I can't link it with the css to get the left and right buttons working. Can someone help me or point me in the right direction?

```css
<style>

.carousel {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    widht:100%;
    height:250px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:250px;
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 100;
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.carousel-control {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#008c6c;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
    left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
    right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #008c6c;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 {
    display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-bullet {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet {
    color: #008c6c;
}

#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="carousel"> 
   <div class="carousel-inner"> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-1" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true" Checked/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
         <h1>Slide 1</h1> 
         <p> Content here for page one.</p> 
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-2" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
         <h1>Slide 2</h1> 
         <p> Content here for page two.</p> 
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-3" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
         <h1>Slide 3</h1> 
         <p> Content here for page three.</p> 
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-4" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
         <h1>Slide 4</h1> 
         <p> Content here for page three.</p> 
      </div> 
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-1" for="carousel-3">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-1" for="carousel-2">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-2" for="carousel-1">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-2" for="carousel-3">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-3" for="carousel-2">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-3" for="carousel-1">›</label> 
      <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-1">•</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-2">•</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-3">•</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-4">•</label> </li> 
      </ol> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great questions tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community - For starters, when you say " everything I try doesn't work", we don't know a) what you have tried and b) what does not work

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: The left and right buttons seem to be working fine for me. What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the CSS rules for each carousel number. Also notice that the labels each have a `prev` and a `next` arrow, which need to be linked to the proper slide

```css
<style>

.carousel {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    widht:100%;
    height:250px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:250px;
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 100;
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.carousel-control {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#008c6c;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
    left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
    right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #008c6c;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3,
#carousel-4:checked ~ .control-4 {
    display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-bullet {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-4:checked ~ .control-4 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(4) .carousel-bullet {
    color: #008c6c;
}

#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="carousel"> 
   <div class="carousel-inner"> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-1" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true" Checked/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
         <h1>Slide 1</h1> 
         <p> Content here for page one.</p> 
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-2" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
         <h1>Slide 2</h1> 
         <p> Content here for page two.</p> 
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-3" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
         <h1>Slide 3</h1> 
         <p> Content here for page three.</p> 
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-4" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
         <h1>Slide 4</h1> 
         <p> Content here for page four.</p> 
      </div> 
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-1" for="carousel-4">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-1" for="carousel-2">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-2" for="carousel-1">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-2" for="carousel-3">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-3" for="carousel-2">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-3" for="carousel-4">›</label> 
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-4" for="carousel-3">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-4" for="carousel-1">›</label>
      <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-1">•</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-2">•</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-3">•</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-4">•</label> </li> 
      </ol> 
   </div> 
</div>
```